# Map `joint_tests` to a list after fitting a `gls` model

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, emmeans

I am trying to get the type 3 ANOVA table with `emmeans::joint_tests()` from a list with the following code. I don't fully understand the error message.
The code that tutors me came from
[http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~yandell/R_for_data_sciences/curate/tidyverse.html](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Eyandell/R_for_data_sciences/curate/tidyverse.html)

```
library(dplyr)
library(nlme)
library(emmeans)
data("diamonds")
diamonds %>%
  split(.$cut) %>%
  map(~ gls(price ~ x + y + z,  
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
  data = .))%>%
map(summary)
```

The error message seems to suggest that I save my individual models somehow and then apply `joint_tests`. What I don't understand is why the workflow works for `summary` but not for `joint_tests`. When we fit single models, it's `summary(model)` or `joint_tests(model)` that prints the summary table or the ANOVA table, respectively.

```
data("diamonds")
diamonds %>%
  split(.$cut) %>%
  map(~ gls(price ~ x + y + z,  
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
  data = .))%>%
map(joint_tests)

Error in (function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"), : Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed
```

Using `map(~ joint_tests)` gave a weird list like this

```
$Fair
function (object, by = NULL, show0df = FALSE, cov.reduce = range, 
    ...) 
{
    if (!inherits(object, "emmGrid")) {
        args = .zap.args(object = object, cov.reduce = cov.reduce, 
            ..., omit = "submodel")
        object = do.call(ref_grid, args)
    }
    facs = setdiff(names(object@levels), by)
    do.test = function(these, facs, result, ...) {
        if ((k <- length(these)) > 0) {
            emm = emmeans(object, these, by = by, ...)
            tst = test(contrast(emm, interaction = "consec"), 
                joint = TRUE, status = TRUE)
            tst = cbind(ord = k, `model term` = paste(these, 
                collapse = ":"), tst)
            result = rbind(result, tst)
            last = max(match(these, facs))
        }
        else last = 0
        if (last < (n <- length(facs))) 
            for (i in last + seq_len(n - last)) result = do.test(c(these, 
                facs[i]), facs, result, ...)
        result
    }
    result = suppressMessages(do.test(character(0), facs, NULL, 
        ...))
    result = result[order(result[[1]]), -1, drop = FALSE]
    if (!show0df) 
        result = result[result$df1 > 0, , drop = FALSE]
    class(result) = c("summary_emm", "data.frame")
    attr(result, "estName") = "F.ratio"
    attr(result, "by.vars") = by
    if (any(result$note != "")) {
        msg = character(0)
        if (any(result$note %in% c(" d", " d e"))) 
            msg = .dep.msg
        if (any(result$note %in% c("   e", " d e"))) 
            msg = c(msg, .est.msg)
        attr(result, "mesg") = msg
    }
    else result$note = NULL
    result
}
<bytecode: 0x7ff68eb4a0a8>
<environment: namespace:emmeans>

$Good
function (object, by = NULL, show0df = FALSE, cov.reduce = range, 
    ...) 
{
```

Here is how I did `joint_tests` without a list.

```
diamond.gls <-  gls(price ~ x + y + z,  
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
  data = diamonds)
joint_tests(diamond.gls)
model term df1      df2  F.ratio p.value
 x            1 14311.72 4898.859 <.0001 
 y            1 12964.08   46.231 <.0001 
 z            1  8380.71   24.576 <.0001
```

Please see how I can fix it.  Thank you.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for responding. I added an example.

Comment: it's two different models you are fitting, with the gls something more complicated than the lm. which one are you trying to fit? I can foresee that the ```varIdents()``` function inside the gls will pose more of a problem. can you please be a bit more coherent in the example?

Comment: @StupidWolf Thank you for responding. I want `gls` eventually but I used `lm` for simplicity. My understanding is `joint_tests` doesn't care what we supply, as long as it is supported.

Comment: it works around, but it is not meant for compatibility with purrr etc. What happens is that it needs to look into your environment for the data frame again, and inside purrr or lapply etc, this becomes problematic. So you need to specify the variance with a gls , as far as i understood?

Comment: @StupidWolf I need to specify the correlation structure. Here I assume each `color` is allowed to have a different variance (instead of a pooled variance for the whole data set).

Comment: you are ok with using a for loop to obtain the results? It will take a while to tease apart the joint_test function to get it to work inside purrr

Comment: I think this is a scoping issue. If instead of mapping to joint_tests, write a function that fits the model and calls joint_tests, then I think it'd work. The issue is that emmeans() (called by joint_tests()) needs to reconstruct the data and can't find it within the scope of the call.

Comment: Or maybe you can just use `map(joint_tests, data = .)`? That should work if data gets passed to joint_tests.

Comment: @RussLenth Thank you for your suggestions. I'm new to looping and function customization so I haven't gone far yet. The second suggestion did not work. I got this error message `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default`

Comment: OK, I tried it & get the same error as you; but it might work if you put `data = diamonds` instead. Still seems better to write your own function to map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons I will investigate, `joint_tests()` needs the `data` argument when it is a `gls` model, at least when called within the body of a function. To overcome this, we need to write a function that fits the model and runs `joint_tests()`. Here is a parallel illustration:

```
mod_jt = function(dat) {
  mod = gls(breaks ~ tension, data = dat)
  joint_tests(mod, data = dat)
}

warpbreaks %>% split(.$wool) %>% map(mod_jt)
```

... and we get the results:

```
$A
 model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 tension      2  24   7.288 0.0034 


$B
 model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 tension      2  24   4.059 0.0303
```

I think the code you had will work with an `lm` model, at least with the newest version of *emmeans**

Answer (score 1):

We can set up dataset with examples that work:

```
dat = droplevels(subset(diamonds,cut %in% c("Ideal","Premium","Good")))
dat$X = cut(dat$z,c(-0.5,4,11))
dat$clarity = factor(dat$clarity,ordered=FALSE)
dat$color = factor(dat$color,ordered=FALSE)
fit = gls(price ~ X*clarity, weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
data=subset(dat,cut=="Ideal"))
joint_tests(fit)

 model term df1      df2   F.ratio p.value
 X            1 15002.85 12145.835 <.0001 
 clarity      7 11834.99   351.899 <.0001 
 X:clarity    7 11834.99   352.344 <.0001
```

So that works ok for a subset, we need to get it to work. The reason you run into the error is that `joint_tests()` looks into your environment for the data.frame again, and inside map() function this is not possible.

One straight forward way is to use a for loop and store the results in a list:

```
fits = list()

for(i in unique(dat$cut)){

f  = gls(price ~ X*clarity,  
                weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
                data = subset(dat,cut==i))
res = joint_tests(f)
fits[[i]] = list(f=f,res=res)
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need to return ’fits` at the end