# `emmeans` for a gls model doesn't run inside `map`

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, emmeans

This question is inspired by [can't use emmeans inside map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576160/cant-use-emmeans-inside-map?noredirect=1&lq=1), and related to [Map `joint_tests` to a list after fitting a `gls` model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282669/map-joint-tests-to-a-list-after-fitting-a-gls-model) and [`group_by` and keep grouping levels as nested data frame's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334449/group-by-and-keep-grouping-levels-as-nested-data-frames-name)

I want  to wrap several tests into one workflow.

This works, for a `glm` model.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(emmeans)
library(nlme)

diamond_result <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  dplyr::mutate(models=map(data,~glm(price ~ x + y + z + clarity + color,data=.x)),
         jt = map(models, ~emmeans::joint_tests(.x, data = .x$data)),
         means=map(models,~emmeans::emmeans(.x,"color",data=.x$data)),
         p_cont = map(means, ~emmeans::contrast(.x, "pairwise",infer = c(T,T))),
         across(models:p_cont, stats::setNames,  .$cut)) 
> diamond_result$jt
$Ideal
 model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 x            1 Inf 611.626 <.0001 
 y            1 Inf   2.914 0.0878 
 z            1 Inf 100.457 <.0001 
 clarity      7 Inf 800.852 <.0001 
 color        6 Inf 256.796 <.0001 


$Premium
 model term df1 df2  F.ratio p.value
 x            1 Inf 2074.371 <.0001
```

But the same syntax doesn't work for a `gls` model so I stopped at `emmeans()` step. Eventually, I want `joint_tests`, `emmeans`, and `contrast` in the `mutate` step.

```
diamonds_emm2 <-  diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(models=map(data,~gls(price ~ x + y + z + clarity,  
                              weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
                              data =.x)),
                means=map(models,~emmeans::emmeans(.x,"clarity",data=.x$data)),
                across(models:p_cont, setNames,  .$cut))
    Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `means`.
    x undefined columns selected
    ℹ Input `means` is `map(models, ~emmeans::emmeans(.x, "clarity", data = .x$data))`.
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `means`.
x undefined columns selected
ℹ Input `means` is `map(models, ~emmeans::emmeans(.x, "clarity", data = .x$data))`.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
 18. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 19. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))

<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `means`.
x undefined columns selected
ℹ Input `means` is `map(models, ~emmeans::emmeans(.x, "clarity", data = .x$data))`.
Backtrace:
     █
  1. ├─`%>%`(...)
  2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
  5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  6. │   └─mask$eval_all_mutate(dots[[i]])
  7. ├─purrr::map(models, ~emmeans::emmeans(.x, "clarity", data = .x$data))
  8. │ └─.f(.x[[i]], ...)
  9. │   └─emmeans::emmeans(.x, "clarity", data = .x$data)
 10. │     ├─base::do.call(ref_grid, args)
 11. │     └─(function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"), ...
 12. │       ├─emmeans::recover_data(object, data = as.data.frame(data), ...)
 13. │       └─emmeans:::recover_data.gls(...)
 14. │         └─emmeans:::recover_data.call(...)
 15. │           ├─tbl[, vars, drop = FALSE]
 16. │           └─base::`[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE)
 17. │             └─base::stop("undefined columns selected")
 18. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 19.   └─dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
```

The code runs OK at this step.

```
diamonds_emm <-  diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% nest() %>%
  mutate(models=map(data,~gls(price ~ x + y + z + clarity,  
                              weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
                              data =.x)))
```

How do I work around this problem? Thank you.

Update: the `map2` function from Ronak's answer solved the problem at the `means` steps but it won't do pairwise contrasts. What did I miss?

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(models=map(data,~gls(price ~ x + y + z + clarity,  
                              weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
                              data =.x)), 
         means = map2(data, models,~emmeans::emmeans(.y,"clarity",data=.x)),
         p_cont = map2(means, ~emmeans::contrast(.y, "pairwise",infer = c(T,T)))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(across(models:p_cont, setNames,  .$cut)) -> result
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `p_cont`.
x object '.z' not found
ℹ Input `p_cont` is `map(means, ~emmeans::contrast(.y, "pairwise", infer = c(T, T)))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: cut = "Fair".
```

Giving a new name to the input at the `p_cont` step, such as  `~emmeans::contrast(.z, "pairwise", infer = c(T, T)))` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Minor: You can use `group_nest(cut)` to replace the separate `group_by` and `nest` steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass data as well as model in the `emmeans` step using `map2`. For `contrasts` and `joint_tests` you can use `map`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(emmeans)
library(nlme)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(models=map(data,~gls(price ~ x + y + z + clarity,  
                              weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
                              data =.x))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(means = map2(data, models,~emmeans(.y,"clarity",data=.x)),
         p_cont = map(means, contrast, "pairwise"), 
         joint_tests = map(means, joint_tests),
         across(models:joint_tests, setNames,  .$cut)) -> result

result

#   cut       data                models      means       p_cont     joint_tests           
#  <ord>     <list>              <named lis> <named lis> <named li> <named list>          
#1 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × … <gls>       <emmGrid>   <emmGrid>  <summary_emm[,5] [1 ×…
#2 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × … <gls>       <emmGrid>   <emmGrid>  <summary_emm[,5] [1 ×…
#3 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9… <gls>       <emmGrid>   <emmGrid>  <summary_emm[,5] [1 ×…
#4 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × … <gls>       <emmGrid>   <emmGrid>  <summary_emm[,5] [1 ×…
#5 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9… <gls>       <emmGrid>   <emmGrid>  <summary_emm[,5] [1 ×…
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to follow your example and looked into functional programming, but I haven't been able to make the `map2()` to work at the pairwise contrasts. Could you help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to produce duplication. My original question concerns 3 steps, though. It was why the 3 steps wrapped in `map` worked for `glm` but not for `gls`. Your `map2` solution worked for 1 step.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not insist on using the `purrr::map` family, I would suggest to use the new (dplyr 1.0.0) [`rowwise` style](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html). It is less confusing, since you can just use the variable/column names as is and there is no need to choose the correct `map` function and figure out the lambda notation. You just need to wrap the function call in `list(...)`. Only the last call to `across` needs to be called on the ungrouped `data.frame`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(emmeans)
library(nlme)

diamonds_emm_row <- diamonds %>%
  nest_by(cut) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(models = list(gls(price ~ x + y + z + clarity,  
                                  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
                                  data = data)),
                jt = list(joint_tests(models, data = data)),
                means = list(emmeans::emmeans(models, "clarity", data = data)),
                p_cont = list(emmeans::contrast(means, "pairwise", infer = c(T,T)))) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(across(models:p_cont, setNames, .$cut))

diamonds_emm_row
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   cut                   data models      jt                 means     p_cont    
#>   <ord>    <list<tbl_df[,9]> <named lis> <named list>       <named l> <named li>
#> 1 Fair           [1,610 × 9] <gls>       <summary_emm[,5] … <emmGrid> <emmGrid> 
#> 2 Good           [4,906 × 9] <gls>       <summary_emm[,5] … <emmGrid> <emmGrid> 
#> 3 Very Go…      [12,082 × 9] <gls>       <summary_emm[,5] … <emmGrid> <emmGrid> 
#> 4 Premium       [13,791 × 9] <gls>       <summary_emm[,5] … <emmGrid> <emmGrid> 
#> 5 Ideal         [21,551 × 9] <gls>       <summary_emm[,5] … <emmGrid> <emmGrid>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This yields more or less the same result as using `purrr::map`. "More or less", because `identical()` won't show it, since the function call is saved in the attributes (and other places), and differs depending on whether you use {dplyr}'s `rowwise` style or the `map` lambda notation.

```r
diamonds_emm_map <- diamonds %>%
  nest_by(cut) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(models=map(data,~gls(price ~ x + y + z + clarity,  
                                     weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|color),
                                     data =.x)),
                jt = map2(models, data, ~ joint_tests(.x, data = .y)),
                means = map2(data, models, ~ emmeans::emmeans(.y, "clarity", data = .x)),
                p_cont = map(means, ~emmeans::contrast(.x, "pairwise", infer = c(T,T))),
                across(models:p_cont, setNames, .$cut))

map2(diamonds_emm_row, diamonds_emm_map, all.equal, check.attributes = FALSE)
#> $cut
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $data
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $models
#> [1] "Component \"Fair\": Component \"call\": target, current do not match when deparsed"     
#> [2] "Component \"Good\": Component \"call\": target, current do not match when deparsed"     
#> [3] "Component \"Very Good\": Component \"call\": target, current do not match when deparsed"
#> [4] "Component \"Premium\": Component \"call\": target, current do not match when deparsed"  
#> [5] "Component \"Ideal\": Component \"call\": target, current do not match when deparsed"    
#> 
#> $jt
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $means
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $p_cont
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>